# Bootstrap form-inline indenting

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, indentation

So I'm working in bootstrap for the first time and I'm making a form, like so:

```
<div class="input-group col-xs-2">
    <label>Voornaam:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Voornaam">
</div>
<div class="input-group col-xs-2">
    <label>Achternaam:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Achternaam">
</div>
<div class="input-group">
     <label for="adresCaptain" class="control-label">Straatnaam + nr:</label>
     <div>
         <div class="form-inline">
             <div class="form-group col-xs-9">
                 <input type="text" class="form-control" id="streetCaptain" placeholder="Straat"/>
             </div>
             <div class="form-group col-xs-3">
                  <input type="number" class="form-control" id="houseNrCaptain" placeholder="Nr"/>
             </div>
         </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

Now, I've got a problem with the indentation of the "form-inline" part. For some reason, it's more indented than the other parts of the form.

image of result: http://puu.sh/g874J/2579b314e4.png

Any idea why this is the case and how I can make it so that the indentation is the same for every part of the form?

Comment: Why do you have a form inside another form?

Answer (score 0):

Your `col-xs-X` class adds an extra padding to `div`.